# CASE WHEN THEN in hours ELSE in days

Tags: sql-server

I'm working in a failed indicator in SQL Server.

if the `planned_receive_date` is before 12h00pm, the `receive_date` has to be on the same day.

if the `planned_receive_date` is after 12h00, the receive_date can be until next day.

i've got this far. i need the hours to decide if its before or after 12.00.

but in the calculation of failed i need only the day. and its calculating to the hour

Example:

`planned_receive_date 9/3/2014 6:10:00 AM`
`receive_date 9/4/2014 9:57:00 AM`

its calculating FAILED (because of hours) and it should be OK(because of days). weekends excluded. i've got this so far:

```
  (case when (planned_receive_date > DATEADD(HH, 12, DATEDIFF(D, 0, planned_receive_date))) 
THEN
(case 
    when datename(dw,planned_receive_date) = 'Friday' 
    then 
        (case 
       when receive_date > DATEADD(HH, 24, DATEDIFF(D, 0, (planned_receive_date+3))) 
       then 'FAILED' 
       ELSE 'OK' end)
    when datename(dw,planned_receive_date) = 'Saturday' 
    then
        (case when receive_date > DATEADD(HH, 24, DATEDIFF(D, 0, (planned_receive_date+2))) 
       then 'FAILED' 
       ELSE 'OK' end)
    when datename(dw,planned_receive_date) = 'Sunday' 
    then 
        (case when receive_date > DATEADD(HH, 24, DATEDIFF(D, 0, (planned_receive_date+1))) 
       then 'FAILED' 
       ELSE 'OK' end)
else 
(CASE
 WHEN DATEADD(HH, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, receive_date)) = DATEADD(HH, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, planned_receive_date)) 
 THEN    'OK'
        ELSE
        (case 
       when receive_date > DATEADD(HH, 24, DATEDIFF(D, 0, planned_receive_date)) 
       then 'FAILED' 
       ELSE 'OK' end)
    END)        
end)
ELSE
    (CASE 
    WHEN DATEADD(HH, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, receive_date)) > DATEADD(HH, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, planned_receive_date))  
    THEN  'FAILED'
        ELSE  'OK'
    END)
END) 
as failed_indicator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this deals with your requirements, and hopefully you can read relatively easily how I got to each part:

```
CASE WHEN receive_date <
    DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,planned_receive_date),
        1+ --End of the planned day + ...
            CASE
                WHEN DATEPART(hour,planned_receive_date) < 12 THEN 0 --That day only
                ELSE
                    CASE DATEPART(weekday,planned_receive_date)
                        WHEN DATEPART(weekday,'20141209') THEN 3 --Friday
                        WHEN DATEPART(weekday,'20141210') THEN 2 --Saturday
                        ELSE 1 --Next day
                    END
            END
     )
THEN 'OK'
ELSE 'FAILED'
END
```

The two constant dates in there should be just left as is. I know it may initially look like I've hard coded something that will only work this weekend, but in fact the only important parts about them are that I happen to know that they are an (arbitrary) Friday and Saturday. By doing it like this, I don't need to know either the `DATEFIRST` setting that's in force or (as in your original code) what *language* settings are in force.